# Creating a persistent Powershell session in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell, iis

I have a project which calls a bunch of Powershell scripts, a few of which take several minutes to run through and cause the page to timeout. I thought about using Start-Job to run several processes in the background to free up the page from timing out, but each time I run a Powershell command it opens a new instance of Powershell and cannot find any jobs.

```
protected void RunShell()
{
    var Shell = PowerShell.Create();
    Shell.Commands.AddScript(Textbox.Text);
    var results = Shell.Invoke();
    if (results.Count > 0)
    {
        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var psObject in results)
        {
            builder.AppendLine(psObject.BaseObject.ToString();
        }
        Textbox2.Text = builder.ToString();
     }
}

protected void button1_Click(object sender, EventAgrs e)
{
    Textbox1.Text = "Start-Job -ScriptBlock{.\\script.ps1} | Out-String";
    RunShell();
}

protected void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Textbox1.Text = "Get-Job * | Out-String";
    RunShell();
}
```

I am now hoping to create a persistent session of powershell that I am able to send commands to and retrieve the jobs and statuses from. I cannot figure out how to set up this snippet of code as a global variable.

Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: You mention having a page time out. Are these functions being called from an ASP.NET under IIS?

Comment: yes they are. Added tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
PowerShell.Create(CurrentRunspace)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.runspacemode%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Edit:   If you want to share a PowerShell, you can do this (to share it across the entire application, replace `Session` with `Application`):

```
    private PowerShell GetPowerShell()
    {
        PowerShell Shell = Session["PowerShell"] as PowerShell;

        if (Shell == null)
        {
            Shell = PowerShell.Create();
            Session["PowerShell"] = Shell;
        }

        return Shell;
    }
```

Comment: I have not. I will try this out.

Comment: I was able to load the Powershell 4 System.Management.Automation reference and got my project to recognize the command RunspaceMode.CurrentRunspace. I am now getting an error that a PowerShell Object cannot be created that uses the current runspace because there is no current runspace available. How would I preload the runspace to be called again?

Comment: I would guess the first time you don't use the parameter.  Subsequent calls would then use it.   Good Luck!

Comment: I tried adding a switch to run Powershell.Create() on the first go, then the second round run Powershell.Create(RunspaceMode.CurrentRunspace). First try I get errors that 'Shell' has already been defined in this scope. I changed the name to 'Shell2' and get the same results as before; 'Get-Jobs * | Out-String' returns nothing. What am I missing to contruct this code the correct way for subsequent calls to use the method?

Comment: Sorry that didn't work.   I edited my answer to show how to have just one instance of a PowerShell object in Asp.Net.

Comment: I wasn't able to get it to work calling it like a function and returning Shell, but I was able to subsitute the whole thing for 'var Shell = PowerShell.Create()' and it worked great. Thank you for your help.